# Is it possible to put different weights on specific batches of training data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have got a training dataset of five different input features and one output feature and I want to use a regression model to predict the output feature.

However, I know that the first part of the training data is "not as good" as the rest, i.e., the output feature does not correspond excatly to the real value and predictions will be further away from the real value in consequence.
Therefore I would like to give less weight to the first part of the training set (or equivalently more to the resting data). Is there any possibility in scikit learn to do this?
So far I only found possibilities to balance data with regard to weighting features differently but not sequences of data for all existent features and also mainly for classification problems.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of scikit-learn estimators handle a `sample_weights` parameter during fit, which is used to weight the contribution of each sample to the cost function.
For example, having a sample weight equal to 2 for a given sample should be roughly equivalent to duplicating this sample.

The `sample_weight` parameter should be a 1D float array of size `n_samples`.

[Full example with SVM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_weighted_samples.html)

Short version:

```
from sklearn import svm
...
clf_weights = svm.SVC()
clf_weights.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.
However, I would like to use the linear_model.ElasticNet and the MLP which do not have this additional parameter in their fit method.
Do you know whether something similar exists for them?

Comment: Indeed, there is no `sample_weights` in `ElasticNet` and `MLPRegressor`. For MLP, you may use `partial_fit` which should be called for each batch, and call it multiple times for the more reliable batches. In ElasticNet, you may just duplicate the good samples to increase their relative impact. This is rather hackish though. If some batches are really unreliable, you may prefer just discarding them.